# Elementary solution to brainteaser? (Conar's inequality)

Tags: analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x_i\ge0$, $1\le i\le n$
satisfy $\sum x_i^2\le n$.
Claim:
$$
n\sum\sqrt{1+x_i}\ge \sqrt 2
\left(
\sum x_i
\right)^2
.
$$
Let's call this Conar's inequality; the $n=3$ case was
posed by Goran Conar in MAA's *Math Horizons*.
A proof for $n=3$ was given
here via Schur-convexity
https://twitter.com/ElfaroukHarb/status/1667805661839720448

Surely, an elementary proof of reasonable complexity must exist.

Who will rise to the challenge?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Aryeh Show your attempts and I'll show my solution. Without showing attempts your topic would be deleted and I don't want that my solution would be deleted.

Comment: The question has been resolved to my satisfaction. Feel free to edit or close.
https://twitter.com/HHHHdi/status/1676515502561132544

Comment: The question is equivalent to the following: If $X$ is a positive random variable such that $E(X^2)\leq 1$, then $E\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+X}{2}}\right)\geq (E(X))^2.$